# What could cause the JVM to lock up mouse click and keyboard input for a machine?

Tags: java, linux, jvm, deadlock

I am running Java 6 on a Linux machine (RHEL 5) and my program occasionally locks up the input to the computer.  No mouse clicks or keyboard strokes work.  Oddly enough, the mouse cursor can be moved and the CTRL+ALT+F2 command works (although it doesn't bring up a terminal).

Using `top` and `jvisualvm` I see no memory leaks or other issues with the process.  However, the only way to unfreeze the computer is to `ssh` from another computer and kill the java process.  What could possibly be the cause of this behavior?

I can reproduce it occasionally by lowering the memory ceiling.  It seems like deadlock might be here:

```
"Java2D Disposer" daemon prio=10 tid=0xae7d6800 nid=0x4451 in Object.wait() [0xae6ad000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0xb3253070> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:118)
    - locked <0xb3253070> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:134)
    at sun.java2d.Disposer.run(Disposer.java:127)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: *"the only way to unfreeze the computer is to ssh from another computer and kill the java process"*... That would quite a broken Linux setup ; )   If this proves to be a problem recompile a kernel with MagicSysRQ compiled in (you may already have it).  It offers, amongst other, the possibility to intercept keystrokes at a much lower level and kill processes etc.  Can become handy when you have an uptime of six months and/or don't want to reboot and have no way to SSH in...

Comment: @GarretHall: also if CTRL+ALT+F2 is "kinda" working, I'm pretty sure that the shortcut allowing to kill your X server would still be working too.  My point is: SSH is very probably *not* the only way to unlock your system ; )    (+1 to your question that said)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symptoms that you describe seem to me as an unreleased X11 keyboard&pointer grab. This can easily be caused by buggy or unresponsive GUI -> X11 layer. Check your GUI thread carefully.

Comment: In my case [SPSW](https://github.com/aploese/spsw) was misbehaving when supplied with an invalid comport handle. No idea what this has to do with GUI except that it freezes (part of) the kernel

Answer (score 1):

The most likely thing is that you're performing a long running task on the Event Dispatch Thread, preventing it from servicing user input events, thus making your UI unresponsive.

You could verify this by running jstack or JConsole and looking at the stack trace for "AWT EventQueue".

Another alternative is that you're performing a legitimate UI task but have inefficiencies in the underlying code.  For example, you may have defined a `JTable` containing 1000,000 rows and have based the underling `TableModel` on a `LinkedList`, leading to O(n) access per row.